# Including 3 different R plots into a single screen

Tags: r, plot

I'm wondering how to fit the **BELOW 3 R plots** into single screen using the matrix structure below?

**Note:** I have annoted the code but the best way is to run each plot to see how it looks.

**Here is my R code:**

```
m2 <- matrix( c( 0,2,2,2,2,     1,2,2,2,2,     1,2,2,2,2,     0,2,2,2,2  ), nrow=5, ncol=4) # matrix m2

m3 <- matrix( c( 0,2,2,2,2,0,   1,2,2,2,2,3,   1,2,2,2,2,3,   0,2,2,2,2,0), nrow=6, ncol=4) # matrix m3

TL <- T ## NOW TRUE

if(TL==T) {layout(m3)}else{layout(m2)}  ## IF TL==T, split the screen according to *m3*


## Plot # 1: ###############################################
curve(dcauchy(x,0,1),-6,6,yaxt="n",bty="n",xaxs="i",xlab="GG",font.lab=2,lwd=2,col="cyan2",ylab = "")


## Plot #2: ###############################################
plot(1, 1, type = "n", xlim = c(0,1.5), ylim = c(.01, 3),log="y", bty="n", axes=F, xaxs="i",
xlab = "GGG", ylab=expression(paste(bold('BBB'))),font.lab=2,cex.lab=2)


axis(side=1, at = seq(0,1.5,.25),labels = c("0",".25",".5",".75","1","1.25","1.5"))
axis(side=2, at = c(.01, 1/30, 1/10, 1/3, 1, 3),labels = c("1/100", "1/30", "1/10", "1/3", "1", "3"),las=1)

axis(side=4,at = c(.01, 1/30, 1/10, 1/3, 1,3),labels = F)
axis(side=4,at = c(.01*1.8, (1/30)*1.7, (1/10)*1.8, (1/3)*1.7, 1*1.7), c("YES", "NO", "YES", "NO", "NO"),tick=F,las=1,font=2,
 mgp=c(1.5,.3, 0),cex.axis=1.8)


## Plot #3: ###############################################
ci <- c(0.09253967, 0.48434172)
plot(1, 1, ty="n" ,ann=F, yaxt="n", bty="n", xlim=c(ci[1], ci[2]), ylim=c(0, 1), xaxt="n")
axis(side = 1, at = ci)
arrows(ci[1], .01, ci[2], .01, code=3, lwd=2, angle = 90, length = .08 )
mtext(side=1,"GGG",line=2.8, font=2, cex= 1.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the heights and widths parameters to `layout`: I got what might be close to your goal with:

```
 png(height=11, width=8, units="in", res=72)
 if( TL ) {layout(m3, widths=c(3, 2,2,3), heights=rep(1.2, ncol(m3)) )
             }else{
              layout(m2)}
    #.... your code here
 dev.off()
```

Still might need some tweaking of the margins or positioning of the `mtext` since the extra large letters on the side seem to expand over the edge of the plotted regions.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any way I can make the `width=` and `height=`  parameters within the `layout()` fluid? I mean if plot changes in any way these two parameters automatically adjust themselves?

Comment: The default for width and height are a series of 1's repeated the proper number of rows and columns, so you would need to be more specific about what sort of "fluidity" you were hoping for.

Comment: The only reason I used `png` was to create an image that you can see. You should be able to set up your OS-specific, interactive screen device to have adequate size to hold these plots.

Comment: Oh, is there a way I can match my device settings to yours so I can replicate what you're showing above?

Comment: I'm on a mac so this works for me: `quartz(height=11, width=8, dpi=72)`, On NIX devices you would use X11(), for Windows; `windows`, but I cannot test any code on that device for obvious reasons.